# Can't browse tagged questions if tag has no bounties

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, bountied-tab

Step 1: Browse to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?sort=featured&pagesize=50.

Step 2: Browse to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki.

This results in:

```
You are on the Featured tab.

There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.

Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?
```

Only thing is, there are no tabs shown, so it's not possible to do so and actually view any questions for the tag in question!

Apparently it's remembering that I'd last used the Featured tab for [ruby], and it defaults to that for [mediawiki] as well, and then blows up because there are no bounties for it.  Oops?

Comment: I [see tabs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k42Xs.png)...

Comment: You do?  I see a bunch of greyed-out words.

Comment: I have the same problem - search on a tag and get the same "no questions / feature tab" result.

Comment: So two users agree that this is a real problem, and I get two downvotes as my reward?  Sigh.

Comment: You missed the actual bug which is that there is no selected tab, thus the tabs don't really look like tabs. It's a design issue, you can still click the tabs and it work flawlessly. Dunno if its worth rewording the report, maybe start new report, focusing on the design part rather than functional part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the lists generally remember what kind of sorting you were using between each tab, so you don't have to keep putting it in the URL, etc. This is intentional. It's so if you leave, and come back (where there won't be information in your URL), it will remember your sorting preferences you used previously. It's actually very handy. Your sorting preferences only get changed if the variables are specified in the URL, otherwise it uses what is stored for you.

It shows the tabs for me though... All you have to do is click one.

[image: example]

Comment: Whoah!  Never noticed that before, and I've been on StackOverflow for two years and hitting this problem randomly for all that time (didn't connect it to tab stickiness until I started writing this).  But that's still serious usability fail, as those are not tabs, but small, greyed-out words.  Since I _am_ on the Featured tab, why not show the tab then?